# read data from CombiTimeTable in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I want to read data from CombiTimeTable and I will save them in different variables.
for me I upload a txt file in combitimetable which contain 7 columns that represent temperature values, now I would like to read each column separately.

--------txt file---------------
[temperature values.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhgx4.png)